# Does somebody know how to get the fan of the fans page in Facebook (FB) without fans detail data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I just want to get the fans discussion contents without any detail data about fan data like ID / Name etc. I wish I can use FaceBook graph to get chat contents,
Thank you for your patience if you have read my question to the end.

Comment: _“I wish I can use FB graph to get chat contents’_ – you can’t. Chat API has been completely removed by Facebook, and all access to a user’s messages is in the process of removal as well.

Comment: Thanks CBroe for your replay , however even if I pay some money for it to FB , it can be happen ??? thanks

Comment: No. There is no way to pay to get access to this data.

Comment: OK I see , thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FB did't share free data in V2 version , so that here is no way to pay to get access to this data or Since v2.0 it's no longer possible to search for public posts, so: No, it's not possible